# how to detect a click of a grid inside an iframe?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, iframe

I have to put a grid inside a iframe. I select a row then the detail is loaded in the main page hosting that frame. How to do?

An image is better than 1000 words. I want to reproduce a master-detail view like wufoo.
The "black" grid is inside of the iframe. So the grid is always on top. Selecting a row, the detail page will be loaded on the back.

how to have a post on the main page when a row-clicked event fires in an iframed-grid, in asp.net mvc?

[image]
<sub>(source: [flickr.com](https://farm2.static.flickr.com/1310/1468761989_e9f91d2cbb_o.png))</sub>

Comment: I changed idea. I use a div with {position:fixed; z-index:1000;}. For the grid a use a jquery grid plugin. The I coded the event OnSelectRow pointing a new page through an ajax call provided by jquery itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't an answer to your actual question, but if you used properly sized divs with CSS of "overflow: auto", you could get the same layout without needing to communicate across frames.

Comment: it's really hard to communicate between frames. I give up and I decided to use divs. Thx for your tip.

Answer (score 1):

Within the iframe:

The "top" variable (or window.top or self.top) should reference the main frame. You could use something like top.location = nextUri;

Alternatively there is a "target" attribute on links which can specify alternate frames. 
The link markup would be something like `<a href="uri1" target="_top">`. You could forward click-events from the row to the link with document.getElementsByTagName("a")[0].click(), assuming that the link is the first one in the row. (The `<base>` element could also be used.)

Remember that replacing the main frame will require the iframe to be reloaded.